# "The import java.util cannot be resolved" for OpenCV2.4.8 Android SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv

Last night I was fed up with the slow debugging of AVD and somewhere I found about HAXM. Which  is basically hardware acceleration support.  [SO-LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow/13856866#13856866) Shows how to install it for ADT. All went fine until I restarted ADT and then I started to get the error on java.util in one of the OpenCV sdk files. Screen below shows the error.
[image]

How do I fix this problem. I hope it had nothing todo with HAXM!
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like java(jdk) libs are not available in classpath ( build classpath).

Comment: How do I fix that? I mean where do I set the classpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries.
2. Remove the Library "Unable to get system library for project".
3. now select Android from left menu -> tick the appropriate version of android under Project Build Target.
4. Click on apply and then OK.
5. Now clean your project.
6. Right click on project -> Android tools -> Fix Project Properties.